# A random result for area of plane

Tags: integration, graphing-functions, area

In cartesian coordinate system we take the x-y plane a d draw the line x=y in 1st quadrant now we can say that this line divides the plane of 1st quadrant into two equal halves which means area under this line will represent half of the area and 1/8th of area of plane

---

On integrating to find area under the curve we get
Area of half plane as x^2/2 x being positive which means the total area of a plane has to be ×8 of this area I.e 4x^2 which represents equation of a parabola .

---

Conclusion: area of the plane is represented by parabolic equation . Is there any logic behind it or did I do something wrong

Comment: You've certainly calculated the area of the subset of the plane with no coordinate exceeding the number $x$. It's not quite right that the area of your eighth is $\tfrac 12 x^2$, though. That's just an indefinite integral representing the area of that eighth with horizontal coordinate between $0$ and $x$. The only way to talk about the area of the *whole* thing is to just say it's infinitely large.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen what if I take finite variables like 5,6 why would area of a square be in the form of a parabola

Comment: If you plot the area of a square against the length of its sides you definitely do get a parabola! In fact if you plot the area of any two-dimensional shape as you scale it against some reference length, the growth is parabolic. It's not so weird if you just think of parabolas as functions involving *squaring*.